# How to vary the value of argument parser in a certain range?

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I am trying to run this piece of code. I want to assign different values to FLAGS.Ncolor as given is x. But when I run this code it is picking the default value of Ncolor that is 2.

```
`p=argparse.ArgumentParser()
passes to add_argument()
p.add_argument('--Ncolor','-nc', default=2, type=int, help='Number of 
colors')
FLAGS=p.parse_args()
x = [ i+1 for i in range(5)]
for FLAGS.NCOLOR in x:
    print ("value is %d" % (FLAGS.Ncolor))`
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: There must be all case sensitive variable names ! You need to change the `for FLAGS.NCOLOR in x:` to `for FLAGS.Ncolor in x:`

Comment: why do even need argparser, when you want to iterate over a list based on hard coded range

Comment: Because in my actual code I have to vary value of Ncolor. I want to know can we assign it a range of values?

Comment: yes, checkout my updated answer. Also checkout the link to argparse, in particular the arguments for add_argument , nargs='+'.

Comment: Before you try to do anything fancy, `print(FLAGS)` to see the values thate the `parse_args` has set.  In this case I expect `FLAGS.Ncolor` to be an integer, default of `2`, but it could be something else depending on how you call the script.

Comment: For an iteration use something like `for i in x: ...`; don't try to use `FLAGS.NCOLOR` as the iteration variable.  It might work, but it is poor style, and probably confusing you.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be mixing up the variables. FLAGS.Ncolor is the value given from the commandline. Which would be for example FLAGS.Ncolor = 5 (the default value in your code would be 2 ). In above code I would add a COLORS var:

```
p=argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument('--Ncolor','-nc', default=2, type=int, help='Number of colors')
FLAGS=p.parse_args()
colors = [c for c in range(1,FLAGS.Ncolor+1)]
for c in colors:
    print ("value is %d" % c)
```

so you get a list colors with the number of values you want.

I think you didnt properly understand what argparse is doing in the code and what you get back from p.parse_args(). Check out the argparse doc for example : [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#module-argparse)

if you want to add the numbers from the commandline directly you could do (notice the new 'nargs="+"' argument in add_argument()):

```
p=argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument('--Ncolor','-nc', default=2, type=int, nargs='+',help='Number of colors')
FLAGS=p.parse_args()

for c in FLAGS.Ncolor:
    print ("value is %d" % c)
```

Hope that helps

You can then do something like that at the CLI:

```
python your_script.py -nc 1 2 3 8 100 255
```

Best

Comment: I know that the arparse is used to change the value from command line.At one time we can only assign it one value. but in above code i want to vary that value in a certain range. Is it possible?

Comment: @sara, maybe you can give a manual example(s) of what you want; i'm not sure i fully understood; if the above response is good for then no worries

Answer (score 0):

Your code, after setting up the parser, is essentially doing:

```
In [195]: import argparse
In [196]: FLAGS = argparse.Namespace(Ncolor=2)
In [197]: FLAGS
Out[197]: Namespace(Ncolor=2)
In [198]: for FLAGS.NCOLOR in range(3):
     ...:     print(FLAGS)
     ...:     
Namespace(NCOLOR=0, Ncolor=2)
Namespace(NCOLOR=1, Ncolor=2)
Namespace(NCOLOR=2, Ncolor=2)
```

Use of `FLAGS.NCOLOR` as the iteration variable is not normal, but it does work - in a way.  It sets the attribute of the `Namespace`.  But why would you want to do that?  Usually that's the job of the `parse_args` method.

`for FLAGS.NCOLOR in ...` works because the `for` statement assigns a value to `FLAGS.NCOLOR`, and `FLAGS` is a simple object class that accepts that kind of assignment.

A more normal iteration would be:

```
In [199]: FLAGS = argparse.Namespace(Ncolor=2)
In [200]: for i in range(3):
     ...:     print(i, FLAGS, FLAGS.Ncolor)
     ...:     
0 Namespace(Ncolor=2) 2
1 Namespace(Ncolor=2) 2
2 Namespace(Ncolor=2) 2
```

where `i` is the temporary iteration variable (just as used in your `x=[]` list comprehension.